# Formula needed to find a date = or < a specific date and return the value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a sheet with column A as an ID number (some duplicates included)

There are 3 other columns involved. C [Edit Date], E [Old Value], and F [New Value].

What I need is a way to find all the edit dates for any ID number equal to or less than a specific date, and then return the date from column E.

I'm not sure if a formula is  the solution but it was my first thought. Any input appreciated.

Thanks

Example:

[image]

Comment: What if there are multiple that meet that criteria?  It would be best if you would mock up some data and expected output and [edit] your post to include these.

Comment: Please clarify. In your question, you want to return a date from column F. On your screenshot, you are looking to return a date from Column E.  Also, please show what you have tried so far, and what your expected results would be.

Comment: Yes column E, my apologies

Comment: I tried this ```=MAX((Table3[Case ID]=ID)*(Table3[Edit Date]<myDate)*Table3[Old Value])``` which was your response @Ron Rosenfeld and I tried a formula that has since disappeared from this thread. Your suggestion gave me an error of #NAME?

Comment: @BillLittlejohn Most likely you did not set up a **Table**.  Suggest you read Excel Help for **Create and format tables**, and be sure the names match.  Also, the values that you show in column `New Value` in your example don't seem to match your rules.  Can you clarify that?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Scott, would be nice to see an example data set.  Anyway, here's my attempt at what you're looking for:

```
=IF(C2<=$M$2,F2,"NO MATCH")
```

To explain the formula:  IF Edit Date is less than or equal to Specific Date, return New Value, if criteria not met, report back "NO MATCH".

C2 is Edit Date
M2 is Specific Date
F2 is New Value

Comment: Not sure how  to add example. I can't seem to find a way to upload file or when I try to paste the excel data from an example it wants to treat it as a pic.

Comment: post the pic @BillLittlejohn  If you cannot post the pic to imgur.com and past the link but do that to your original post.

Comment: The problem with that is the  CaseID. So there maybe several edits on 1 CaseID. So it would need to pull only the most recent = or less than the search date.

Comment: Example posted above.

Comment: I'm not opposed to using VBA but  I wouldn't know how to begin...